# Did cryptokitties have a negative effect on Ethereum?

Tags: cryptokitties

I received a comment from a professional Bitcoin exchange where the person said that cryptokitties have had a negative effect on the ether. What could that mean? Is it true?

Comment: Hi there. Questions which lead to opinion-based answers are considered off topic for this site, I'm afraid. Reddit is a better place to ask: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum

Comment: Perhaps you could re-phrase this to be neutral/objective; "quantify the effect of X on the ethereum platform, in terms of transaction throughput.. etc?"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, one could say that. CryptoKitties actually tested Ethereum's capabilities in terms of scalability and transaction speed. At one stage, more than 10% of total Ethereum transactions belonged to people playing CryptoKitties which resulted in Ethereum network congestion. Eventually number of pending transactions increased significantly some of which took days to confirm.

And CryptoKitties is probably the first popular app built on Ethereum. Assume what would happen if 10 or more such apps are active simultaneously on Ethereum network?